# How to combine two shapefiles using a common attribute in R?

Tags: r, join, gis, arcgis, shapefile

I have two shapefiles `sf1` and `sf2` for same area. sf1 is population data for year 2015 and has 6 variables.

[image]

`sf2` is population data for year 2010 and has 5 variables.

[image]

Both have one common attribute `GEOID`. I want to get a combined layer with 8 variables (6 from 2015 and the 2 (variable and value) from 2010).

How can I combine the two shapefiles using the common attribute `GEOID` in R (same as `join` in ArcGIS? I tried merging them.

```
sf3 <- merge(sf1, sf2)
```

It merges the two layers to give me 11 variables. This is not what I want. I want to join the attribute tables for the two layers and get one of the common attributes.

I tried `inner_join()`, which gives me the error

> Error: y should not have class sf; for spatial joins, use `st_join()`.

I tried `st_join()` but got 229 obs. of 10 variables. I just want same # of variables with 8 variables.

Comment: Try `inner_join(sf1, sf2, by="GEOID")`

Comment: I did try that. I got error saying "Error in UseMethod("inner_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'inner_join' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector')"

Comment: It looks like your geometries aren't the same for each GEOID between years, so `st_join` returns something you're not expecting. The default join is 'st_intersects`. Either try another join method for `st_join` or pick which year's geometry to use & drop the other geometry allowing for a `left_join`.

Comment: You can't generally use spatial data types with sf functions. Make sure your data are sf objects using `st_as_sf`